# SQLite will let you place multiple queries in a transaction, but why does it freak when 1 has a fK_relation to the other?

Tags: transactions, sqlite

I have 2 queries i was wanting to execute.

```
delete from song where ast_id = 1;
delete from artist where ast_id = 1;
```

There is a relationship with the 2.  1 has a FK which references the other.

I was thinking that the queries would be executed together, but i was thinking that if executed in proper order, would delete the songs from the artist and then the artists themselves.  THis was not the case.

I ended up solving it by just breaking it into 2 transactions, but is there a way to keep it just 1?

I was doing something along the lines of:

```
string query("delete from song where ast_id = 1; delete from artist where ast_id = 1;");
sqlite3_exec(db, query.c_str(),...);
```

Can do you it in 1 transaction such as above/?

Comment: Please note that giving two commands to `sqlite3_exec` will not execute them in one transaction; you have to actually execute the `BEGIN`/`COMMIT` commands.

Comment: Please show the schema, the error message, and on which command you get the error.

Comment: Other people have explained how to use transactions, you appear to be executing two sequential commands in separate, autocommitted transactions.  What I don't understand is why two separate statements won't work unless you have your FOREIGN KEY defined on the wrong table (it should be on song, not artist).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One approach, as stated, is to start a transaction (which is not the same as a command), add the queries, and commit.

(Note this is pseudo code, I'm not sure what platform you're using)

```
sqlite3_exec(db, "begin;");
sqlite3_exec(db, "delete from song where ast_id = 1;");
sqlite3_exec(db, "delete from artist where ast_id = 1;");
sqlite3_exec(db, "commit;");
```

But the way to do it with a foreign key is to ensure foreign keys are enabled in the first place.

You can check if they are enabled with:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys;
```

Or just turn them on with:

```
PRAGMA foreign_keys = ON;
```

For your Song table, your reference must be properly formed, you have to say what you want to do on delete thus:

```
Create Table Song
(
  Song_Id Integer Primary Key,
  ...
  Ast_Id Integer,
  Foreign Key (Ast_Id) References Artist(Ast_Id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);
```

Then, just delete the artist and the songs will follow.