# VB.Net SQLite last_insert_rowid always return 1 using edmx (EF6)

Tags: vb.net, sqlite, entity-framework-6

I've done lots of research, read lots of posts, and I found none using edmx (Entity Data Model) with EF6.
Here is my problem:
Simple table...

```
CREATE TABLE Oops (
OopsID INTEGER       NOT NULL
                     PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
UserID INTEGER       NOT NULL
                     REFERENCES Users (UserID),
Reason VARCHAR (100) NOT NULL
```

);

I am trying to retrieve the last OopsID inserted.
In VB.Net I have tried the following:

```
Dim dbContext As New RCA.Entities
```

```
' Always returns 1
Dim rtnVal1 As Int64 = dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO Oops (UserID,Reason) VALUES(" & clsShared.iUserID & ",'" & txtReason.Text & "'); SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM Oops;")

' Always returns -1
Dim rtnVal2 = dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO Oops (UserID,Reason) VALUES(" & clsShared.iUserID & ",'" & txtReason.Text & "'); SELECT SEQ from sqlite_sequence WHERE name='Oops';")
```

However the following query in SQLiteStudio return 7, the correct value:

```
SELECT SEQ from sqlite_sequence WHERE name='Oops'
```

It seems as if the 2 commands in one statement would be processed on different connections, which I doubt.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure that `ExecuteSqlCommand` even supports multiple statements?

Comment: Actually, now that you mention it I just remember running a query to create 2 triggers in DDL and only 1 was created. Oh my, I realize more and more that SQLite is indeed a bit too Lite in the knees.

Well, if you are right (which I suspect you are) then there is no safe way to retrieve the last inserted ID in a multithreaded environment, sound like ACCESS. I believe now the value "1" I'm getting in rntVal1 might just be the number of rows created.

Comment: Actually I just read your response to another post [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13936941/sqlite-will-let-you-place-multiple-queries-in-a-transaction-but-why-does-it-fre) where you state, "Please note that giving two commands to sqlite3_exec will not execute them in one transaction; you have to actually execute the BEGIN/COMMIT commands." did you mean by that in one statement? If so do you know how to handle the transaction with EF6? The only object I know to manipulate is the dbContext.Database and it only offers BeginTransaction, no CommitTransaction, kind of weird.

Comment: SQLite itself can do what you want, but I don't know how EF6 works. In any case, I recommend reading [its documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/dn456843.aspx).

Comment: Thank you very much, you pointed me in the right direction. After doing more reading I realized I was using the wrong command, "ExecuteSqlCommand" instead of "SqlQuery"...see my code at the end of this post, it finally works.

Answer (score 1):

This code finally worked for me:

```
    Using dbContextTransaction = dbContext.Database.BeginTransaction()
      Try
        dbContext.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("INSERT INTO Oops (UserID,Reason) VALUES(" & clsShared.iUserID & ",'" & txtReason.Text & "')")
        Dim rtnVal = dbContext.Database.SqlQuery(Of Int64)("SELECT last_insert_rowid();").ToList

        dbContextTransaction.Commit()
      Catch generatedExceptionName As Exception
        dbContextTransaction.Rollback()
      End Try
    End Using
```

An FYI, the value "1" I was originally getting from ExecuteSqlCommand was the number of rows affected.

Answer (score -1):

you should write

```
SELECT SCOPE_IDENTITY()
```

to get last inserted id

Comment: Not in SQLite, I don't think so.

Comment: I confirm after testing. I received the error message, "SQL logic error or missing database no such function: SCOPE_IDENTITY"